# How to parse a xaml file/string

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

I'm reading an xaml file using `XamlReader()` and it has of course elements and attributes such as:

```
<setter property="Property1" Value="Value1" />
```

Are there any methods to locate a specific property and its associated value?

Should I parse the string using string functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSDN docs show using an XmlReader as input to XamlReader

```
// Load the button
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(savedButton);
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
Button readerLoadButton = (Button)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx

You could just use the XmlReader to grab attributes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28VS.95%29.aspx

You would use `XmlNodeType.Attribute` in the `switch` statement shown in the MSDN example, after first noting the node you're in in the `XmlNodeType.Element` case.