# Is there a way to manipulate xaml file in c# programmatically at runtime?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, translation

The aim of my project is to manipulate xaml code so as to convert the existing Xaml UWP code into different platform Xaml Code. Any help will be appreciated.

```
StreamReader stream = new StreamReader("Path to xaml file");
FrameworkElement root = XamlReader.Load(stream.BaseStream) as FrameworkElement;
```

The issue here is the xaml file contains x:class which apparently cannot be load in the runtime. So is there a better way to manipulate the attributes.

Comment: You need to use XAML parsers and then parse from one format, to another &mdash; just like JSON or XML serializers and parsers. But since you have not shown interest in explaining yourself, or the code you tried, there is little I can help you with.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan I am in the initial phase of it and haven't written anything , just wanted to know which parser can convert the xaml file into a tree so as to manipulate easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine XamlReader.Load and XamlServices.Parse to load and parse xaml files programmatically:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xaml.xamlservices.parse(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590388(v=vs.110).aspx

[How to parse a xaml file/string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973393/how-to-parse-a-xaml-file-string)

https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/framework/xaml-services/xamlservices-class-and-basic-xaml-reading-or-writing.md

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ashish/2007/08/14/dynamically-loading-xaml/